# Portaudio reading SDRSharp I/Q File

Tags: c++, portaudio

I have AM I/Q wave file that can be played on SDRSHARP. I want to make it play through **portaudio** at first without performing any kind of demodulation. before that i want to clear my concepts through these questions.

1. The sample file is seen as 22050 sample rate sample file with 32bit floating points sample in audacity software. Now these files are saved from USB dongle data sampled at 2.048 Msps by RTL2832u ADC using sdrsharp. So how should i read it when file sample rate is 22050? Should i consider it as live source with I/Q samples coming at rate of 22050 samples/sec, this sampling rate is important as it would be required for applying DSP technique like filtering etc?
2. I have made a small program using portaudio to redirect whatever it has input(microphone) to output (speakers) using callback, How can i read my any wave file using same call back whereas in my call back i have taken **framesperbuffer** to be 256 what value it should be for wave file saved at 22050 sample rate, there must be some relation between **framesperbuffer** and file **sample rate**?.  i am using C++ (Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: i have figured out that portaudio cant be used for reading wave file and it recommends libsndfile for this. Even then i am not getting the reading whether the reading rate is important, i mean how much to read for playing through port audio.

Comment: i am reading 256 samples periodically from file as if reading from soundcard but i dont know whether this I/Q data needs to be filtered before demodulation or it is already filtered and saved ready for demodulation. Does any one has working experience with sdrsharp I/Q wave data file samples or any useful informtion?